# update SMBIOS tables

Tags: bios, uefi

Is there a standard way to update the SMBIOS table, to add new variables?

For example, if I would like to change a variable such as 'mainboard name', or more generically, add a new entry in the table to define custom struct and value, what would be the standard way to implement this, so that I can query this value with dmidecode, /sys/class/dmi, or libsmbios?

Obviously, the board manufacturers have tools to change such values in the SMBIOS table, and which can be accessed from operating system in a standard way.

The /sys/firmware/dmi/tables interface seems to be read-only. Can one write to the respective area under /dev/mem (using smbios_entry_point) to add new entries?

Is there an alternative standard and modern way to save such (custom) hardware information, to avoid having to query the hardware component directly? from UEFI?

Answer (score 0):

There is such an option for COM Express® module. The PICMG specification depict an EEPROM on the Carrier Board that can hold SMBIOS data. Take a look at following specification:
https://www.picmg.org/wp-content/uploads/PICMG_EeeP_R1_0.pdf
There is a source code for updating the EEPROM at: https://sourceforge.net/projects/eapidk/

But in COM Express® Carrier Design Guide https://www.picmg.org/wp-content/uploads/PICMG_COMDG_2.0-RELEASED-2013-12-06.pdf there is following statement

> The EEPROM stores configuration information for the system of the Carrier Board. The data
> structure used is defined in the PICMG EEEP Specification. The Specification recommends but
> does not require the use of this system configuration EEPROM. The Module BIOS may check
> the Carrier Board configuration EEPROM but is not required to do so by the Specification.

Which allow BIOS/Firmware vendor to skip this EEPROM.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).